# Arcore flutter, collide moving objects with camera

Tags: flutter, position, android-camera, arcore

I have been learning Flutter for the last 3 weeks. As an endgoal I´m trying to create an endless runner variant with AR (read: something like "Subway surfers). The idea is that the player would really have to avoid the obstacles with his camera. To do this I used the ArCore plugin for Flutter.

I can spawn my objects. Im also able to move the object.

The part that i cant figure out is how to get the camera´s position, and detect a collision with the obstacles.

How can i detect the camera´s position in Flutter ARCore, to detect wether a Cube has collided with it?

I have tried with camera position, and getCameraPosition and such. But these functions arent defined.

This is the code so far:

````
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flame/game.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:arcore_flutter_plugin/arcore_flutter_plugin.dart';

class ArScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ARScreenState createState() => _ARScreenState();
}

class _ARScreenState extends State<ArScreen> {
  late ArCoreCube cubeRenderable;
  late ArCoreController arCoreController;
  int count = 0;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initializeModels();
  }

  void initializeModels() {
    cubeRenderable = ArCoreCube(
      materials: [
        ArCoreMaterial(
          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 0, 0),
        ),
      ],
      size: Vector3(50, 50, 50),
    );
  }

  bool isARViewReady = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('AR App'),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          ArCoreView(
            onArCoreViewCreated: _onArCoreViewCreated,
            enablePlaneRenderer: true,
            enableTapRecognizer: true,
            enableUpdateListener: false,
          ),
          if (!isARViewReady)
            Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onArCoreViewCreated(ArCoreController controller) {
    print("onArCoreViewCreated (plane)");
    arCoreController = controller;
    _setupTapGesture();
    _setupPlaneDetection();
    // Notify that the AR view is ready
    setState(() {
      isARViewReady = true;
    });
  }

  void _setupTapGesture() {
    arCoreController.onPlaneTap = _handleOnPlaneTap;
    print("onPlaneTap set");
  }

  void _setupPlaneDetection() {
    arCoreController.onPlaneDetected = _handleOnPlaneDetected;
    print("onPlaneDetected set");
  }

  void _handleOnPlaneDetected(ArCorePlane plane) {
    print("Plane detected: ${plane.type}");
    // Handle the plane detection event here
  }

  void _handleOnPlaneTap(List<ArCoreHitTestResult> hits) {
    int countTap = 0;
    print("tapped on plane");
    final hit = hits.first;
    final cube = ArCoreCube(
      size: Vector3(0.1, 0.1, 0.1),
      materials: [ArCoreMaterial(color: Colors.red)],
    );
    countTap++;
    Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 100), (timer) {
      final node = ArCoreNode(
        shape: cube,
        position: hit.pose.translation +
            Vector3(
                0,
                0,
                -timer.tick *
                    0.01), // Move the cube towards the camera over time
        rotation: hit.pose.rotation,
        name: "cube$count",
      );
      arCoreController.addArCoreNode(node);
      print("${node.name} addded");
      count++;

      Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
        arCoreController.removeNode(nodeName: "cube${count - 2}");
        print("${node.name} removed");
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    arCoreController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```
````